# Selenium how to work with safari Cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to work with Selenium and have problem with cookies it return cookie equals null in method FindCookie, with Google Chrome and FireFox all works good

```
  public void SetCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue)
    {

        var cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
        driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
       // driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, "/"));

    }

    public string FindCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        var cookieNamed = driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed(cookieName);
        if (cookieNamed == null)
            return null;
        return cookieNamed.Value;
    }
```

How I can do works cookie for Safari?